# Value and Text properties in asp.net TextBox (Value gets overwritten by Text )

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have TextBox like below.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name" value="aaaa" text="bbbb"/>
```

in code behind.

```
Dim str As String = Name.Text.Trim() ' value as bbbb
```

If I removed the text property.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name" value="aaaa" /> <%--text="bbbb"--%>    

Dim str As String = Name.Text.Trim() ' value as aaaa
```

whenever I am keeping text property I am not able to access Value field. How to get the value field when text property is present?

Comment: You shouldn't use the Value property, it's not part of the textbox. You should always use Text. Look at the viewsource when you have both value and text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `value` property. If you are using asp.net's `TextBox` you must use `Text`.

When you add properties that don't exists in the TextBox class, asp.net will render those properties to the resulting html. So

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name" text="bbbb" mycustomproperty="hi" />
```

Will render to something like this

```
<input type="text" value="bbbb" id="..." name="..." mycustomproperty="hi"/>
```

If you omit the `TextBox`'s `Text` property and write the value property, then the value property will be rendered.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name" value="aaaa" />
```

To

```
<input type="text" value="aaaa" id="..." name="..."/>
```

TextBox doesn't has a Value property. When the TextBox instance is created, the HTML value property will be assigned to the Text property, and that's why you access the Text property it has the "aaaa" value.

Summary: Don't use value property when you use ASP.NET controls. Use the controls specific properties.

Answer (score 0):

Value isn't a valid property of an asp:Textbox

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to store data associated to a control on the page, then consider using the ASP.NET `HiddenField` control to store values that can be read across post backs to the server, like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="HiddenFieldValue" />
```

Then in code-behind, you can get and set the value via the `Value` property, like this:

```
' Storing value
Me.HiddenFieldValue.Value = "value you want to keep"

' Retrieving value
Dim str As String = Me.HiddenFieldValue.Value
```